# Issue with sheet protection

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a tool where users can create sheets for their individual projects that will later be used to automatically generate powerpoint slides. Everything worked great until I tried to add sheet protection to limit their editing to only the input cells required...

Here is the template sheet that gets copied with a new name whenever they add a new project

[image]

As you can see the sheet is protected, but I can edit the cells I need (D2 for example) because they're not locked

[image]

After I gather some user inputs via a form, I copy the template sheet to a new sheet in the same workbook with this code...wsShortBlank is the template sheet

```
wsShortBlank.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    With ThisWorkbook
        wsShortBlank.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Set sh = ActiveSheet        'the copied sheet should be the active one, so grab a handle to it
    End With
    wsShortBlank.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    sh.Name = txtPE.Value & " " & txtPEC.Value

    Unload Me

    With sh
        .Activate

        .Unprotect password:=myPassword

        'add done editing button
        .Buttons.Add(468.75, 30, 210.75, 60.75).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "doneEditing"
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Done Editing"

        'populate the data we know
        .Range("B33").Value = comboClass.Value
        .Range("B34").Value = txtPE.Value
        .Range("B35").Value = txtPEC.Value
        .Range("B36").Value = txtTask.Value

        .Protect password:=myPassword

        .Range("D2").Select   'stick the cursor in the first input field
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I now have this sheet

[image]

The Done Editing button links to a sub that hides the current sheet and reshows the main menu form

But if I attempt to edit cell D2, I get this

[image]

As if the cell is locked. BUT, if I click over to another sheet and then click back to this sheet, I can edit cell D2 just fine.

What gives?

As an update, I also modified the code so that after copying the sheet it went through and individually set the locked properties of the cells..so this was added toward the end of the above code block

```
        .Range("D2:D7").Locked = False
        .Range("D11:D12").Locked = False
        .Range("C17:J19").Locked = False
        .Range("C23:G23").Locked = False
        .Range("D24:H24").Locked = False
        .Range("E25:I25").Locked = False
        .Range("F26:J26").Locked = False
        .Range("B30:G30").Locked = False


        .Protect password:=myPassword
```

But it made no difference.

Comment: Why don't you create a new worksheet based on the template and fill that out?

Comment: That's exactly what I do...I copy the template worksheet, which has the protections I want set. I unprotect the new copy for a second to populate some title fields and add the "done editing" button, then re-protect it.  The weird behavior is the way it tells me the cell is locked when it isn't, but if i click on another sheet and then come back, it works properly

Comment: Further update.  This issue only appears to happen at work where we have Excel 2013.  I have anewer version at home and everything works as it should.  Any ideas as to how to get around this? I have tried having the code activate other sheets and then come back to the newly copied sheet (trying to mimic the click over/click back solution in code) but that doesn't seem to do it.  It's looks pretty Mickey Mouse if I have to tell my users to do that manually...